# How to use React to create a checkboxes filter function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a filter function in my collection page, when checking one checkbox, and that type of resorts will be rendered.

So in my CollectionPage.js, after fetching all resorts and setting the Resorts state, according to the type param in the url

```
const { type } = useParams();
```

I prepared the array of type objects for the FilterBox.js to use. And the type that match the url param will be Selected: true

```
  const [resorts, setResorts] = useState([]);

  const { type } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://......")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      setResorts(json);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error ${err}`)
    })
  }, [])

  /* get all types array */
  const allType = ["All"];
  resorts.map(item => (allType.push(item.Type)));

  /* get no-repeat types array */
  const collection = allType.filter(
    (ele, pos) => {
      return allType.indexOf(ele) === pos;
    }
  )

  /* set types array for filterBox to use */
  const typeObjs = [];
  collection.map(item => (
    item === type ? (
      typeObjs.push({ Type: item, Selected: true })
    ) : (
      typeObjs.push({ Type: item, Selected: false })
    )
  ));
```

Then, in the child component - FilterBox.js, it receive the typeObjs array as type, to render checkboxes

```
const FilterBox = ({ type }) => {

  return (
    <div className='filter-box'>
        <div className='filter-card'>

          <h3>Select Resorts Type</h3>

          <div className='filter-selection'>
          {
            type.map(item => (
              item.Selected === false ? (
                <div>
                  <Link to = {`/resorts/type/${item.Type}`}>
                  <input type="checkbox" id={item.Type} name="type" value={item.Type} />
                  <label htmlFor={item.Type}> {item.Type}</label>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <Link to = {`/resorts/type/${item.Type}`}>
                  <input type="checkbox" id={item.Type} name="type" value={item.Type} defaultChecked />
                  <label htmlFor={item.Type}> {item.Type}</label>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              )
            ))
          }
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see, checkbox will be checked if it match the current page url param
[image]

And I have wrapped each checkbox within a  tag which will link to the relative type url

```
<div>
     <Link to = {`/resorts/type/${item.Type}`}>
        <input type="checkbox" id={item.Type} name="type" value={item.Type} />
        <label htmlFor={item.Type}> {item.Type}</label>
     </Link>
</div>
```

The issue is, when I click other type, the defaultChecked "All" type wil still be checked, and what I click will not be checked but, the relative resorts will be rendered successfully. Have no idea how to solve this.

Thank you for your time of checking my issue and I appreciate for your help!

Comment: For search query, you have to use `/resorts?type=hostel` Would you want multiple select? or single select?

Comment: In my App.js, the Route is `<Route path='/resorts/type/:type' element={<CollectionPage />}`, then I use `const { type } = useParams()` in CollectionPage.js to get the type. And I want single select.

Comment: Yeah, my suggestion is to change it into `<Route path='/resorts' element={<CollectionPage />} />` and `const q = useQuery(); q.get('type')`

Comment: Edited: useSearchParams should be correct. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sandbox. it creates a custom hook, `useSingleSelect`. It handles an array state whose length is 0 or 1.

useSingleSelect.ts

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const useSingleSelect = (initialValue: string[]) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string[]>(initialValue);
  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (selected.includes(value)) {
      setSelected([]);
    } else {
      setSelected([value]);
    }
  };
  const isSelected = (value: string) => {
    return selected.includes(value);
  };
  return { selected, isSelected, onChange };
};
```

App.tsx

```
import { useSingleSelect } from "./hooks";

const data = ["All", "Resort", "Apartment", "Villa", "Hostel", "Cottage"];

export default function App() {
  const { selected, isSelected, onChange } = useSingleSelect(['All']);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Selected: {selected.join()}</div>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
        {data.map((value) => (
          <li key={value}>
            <input
              id={value}
              type="checkbox"
              value={value}
              checked={isSelected(value)}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor={value}>{value}</label>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/usesingleselect-llor3k?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you so much! Now the checking function works perfectly. Because I want it show relative resorts when checking one box, so I wrap the checkbox in to <Link> tag like this `<Link to = {\`/resorts/type/${value}\`}> ... </Link>`. The resorts can be rendered perfectly, but the checkbox no, sometime it will be checked when I click, sometime no. Seems like the those checkboxes not re-rendering everytime when I go to a new url.

Comment: because you don't pass states when jumping Link. That's also a reason why I suggested url search parameters.